# Anyway to compare two columns that are way different MySQL

Tags: mysql, compare

I'm having a little of a struggle comparing two columns in MySQL.

This is quite hard to explain but I'll try my best.

I have a column called **name** and another one called **locale_name**. Now i need to compare strings from those two columns that have a +number (**between 0-9**) at the end of each string. It would be easy to do so if all the strings had just the number at the end but some of the have other symbols for example

column **locale_name** has Something+2
column **name** has Something+2''

And now i need to somehow skip the symbols at the end and compare just numbers at the end of each string... I hope that made sense. I tried several queries already but i just don't know a way of how to get rid of those symbols or anyway around it.